# What is gradle version which should be used with 3.6.1 android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

My question is simple, with android studio 3.6.1, my existing project have stopped working, I have tried to update below two files only, but no use.
Please note I am not a developer, So I will really appreciate, if solution can be given in layman terms.

I am getting below errors-

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0 available for offline mode.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.6.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dhritiapps.tulsiramayan"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.04"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
   // implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
}
```

second file

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'`

Answer (score 0):

I think this *error* is because your **dependencies** in your *second file* (version `3.6.0`)  aren't the same as your **Android Studio version** (version `3.6.1`) .

Try changing your `dependencies` to:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
}
```

Comment: I didn't saw your comment, I was here before you left your comment

Comment: Why are you lying? My comment shows 20 mins ago and your answer is 6 min ago.

Comment: What do you mean?! I was answering it long before you were here.